# Index with Xindy, last line to long

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am trying to customise my index, based on [this initial question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428632/19326). As i later found out, hyperref and xindy do not play nice if cross references are involved. Which is why I tried to follow [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287809/19326) which disables hyperref for indexin, and builds the links itself from the style file.

While I have some issues with the stylefile and links not working that is another question.

I am interested in why my formatting breaks: I would like pagenumbers to be right aligned, which they are except for the last entry of every lettergroup where the line extends slighlty more to the right.

[image]

Why is that/how do I fix this? (I assume i might do things incorrectly in the `markup-letter-group` at the bottom of the xindy file, as that is the homebrew part)

```
%pdflatex
%xindy index.idx -M indexStyle -L english -C utf8
%pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{indexStyle.xdy}
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers")             
:min-range-length 2)                            

(define-attributes (("definition" "usage" "default" "hyperpage")))


(define-crossref-class "see")
(markup-crossref-list :class "see" :open "\seelinkk{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(define-crossref-class "seealso")
(markup-crossref-layer-list :sep ", ")
(markup-crossref-list :class "seealso" :open "\seealsolinkk{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(define-crossref-class "hyperindexformat")
(markup-crossref-list :class "hyperindexformat" :open
"\hyperindexformat{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")


(define-location-class-order (
"arabic-page-numbers"
"see"
"seealso"))

(markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}
    \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
    \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
        \par\textbf{#1}\par
        \nopagebreak
    }
    \def\tedIDXlvlZero{}
    \def\tedIDXlvlOne{}
    \def\tedIDXlvlTwo{}

    \newcommand{\tedSetter}[1]{
        \if\tedLevel0
        \def\tedIDXlvlZero{#1}
        \else{
            \if\tedLevel1
            \def\tedIDXlvlOne{#1}
            \else
            \def\tedIDXlvlTwo{#1}
            \fi
        }\fi
    }
    \def\tedLevel{0}
    \newcommand{\buildlinktargett}[1]{%
        \if\tedLevel0%
        index:#1%
        \else{%
            \if\tedLevel1%
            index:\tedIDXlvlZero, #1%
            \else%
            %           \ifx\tedLevel\tedIDXlvlTwo %implicit%
            index:\tedIDXlvlZero, \tedIDXlvlOne, #1%
            \fi%
        }\fi%
    }
    \newcommand{\targetindexentryy}[1]{\tedSetter{#1}\hypertarget{\buildlinktargett{#1}}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\seelinkk}[1]{\see{\hyperlink{index:#1}{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\seealsolinkk}[1]{\seealso{\hyperlink{index:#1}{#1}}}
    ~n"     
    :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)


(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{0} \item "            :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{1}    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{2}      \subsubitem " :depth 2)


(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :close "" ) ;; :sep ", "


(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}" :attr "hyperpage")   


(markup-keyword-list :open "\targetindexentryy{" :close "}" )

;;;(require "lang/english/utf8.xdy")

(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n~n \vspace{1cm} {\hfill\bf " :close-head "\hfill}" :capitalize)
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[xindy, nonewpage]{imakeidx} %nonewpage needed for index entries after \printindex

\makeindex[program=truexindy, intoc, options={-M indexStyle -L english -C utf8}]

\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello some useless text.\clearpage
\index{foo}
\index{foo!bar}
\index{bar}
\index{cat}
\index{carbon}
\index{combobreaker}
\index{join}
\index{join!hash}
\index{hash join|see{join, hash}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the last line is right, the other lines are too short:
The code `xindy` generates in the `.ind` file ends up like this:

```
 \vspace{1cm} {\hfill\bf F\hfill}
 \def\tedLevel{0} \item \targetindexentryy{foo}\dotfill \hyperpage{2}
 \def\tedLevel{1}    \subitem \targetindexentryy{bar}\dotfill \hyperpage{2}
```

When reading this code, TeX replaces each end of line by a space, so at the end of every item there is a space. The end of line character for the last item is interpreted differently because it is followed by an empty line, so it just ends the paragraph instead of inserting a space.
This explains why the last line appears a little bit longer: All the other lines have a space character at the right side. To avoid this, you can use the TeX macro trick of ending lines with a `%` to suppress this space: Just replace

```
(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{0} \item "            :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{1}    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{2}      \subsubitem " :depth 2)
```

with

```
(markup-indexentry :open "%~n \def\tedLevel{0} \item "            :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "%~n \def\tedLevel{1}    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "%~n \def\tedLevel{2}      \subsubitem " :depth 2)
```